# grep for text with wild card in between

Tags: linux, sed, awk, grep, tail

I would like to grep something like `==> *.sh <==`. But it doesn't work, I can grep everything up to `.sh <==` but not get the wild card to work.

What's the trick here?

Comment: so, the '==> *.sh <==' is **all** in the file? You need to use a regular expression.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You need to grep for something like `"==> .*\.sh <=="`

The `.*` part matches any character for any length, the `\.` part matches a dot.

Comment: (By way of explanation, "*.sh" is a filename glob pattern, which is a completely different notation for matching than the regular expressions expected by grep.  In regular expressions, * means 0 or more repetitions of the previous expression, which in your case was a space.  A dot means any character at all.  So, " *.sh" could match "    Xsh" but never "file.sh".  Google regular expresions for details / examples etc.)

Comment: @TonyD great comment but use `backquote`s to delimit code or terminology so readers won't have to think was the double quote/quote a part of the command or not