# Bash scripting. grep with wildcard not working

Tags: bash, grep, special-characters, wildcard

Within bash, I'm trying to search (grep) the output of a command (ntp), for a specific string. However, one of the columns in the output is constantly changing. So for that column it could be any character.

I'm probably not doing this correctly, but the `*` is not working like I hoped.

```
ntpq -p | grep "10 l * 64  377  0.000  0.000  0.001"
```

The asterisk is replacing a column that changes from - to 1-64, by the second.

any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: The "re" in grep stands for "Regular Expression".

Comment: This might be useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5906228/grep-for-text-with-wild-card-inbetween

Answer (score 5):

A `*` in regex is different from a `*` in shell globbing. The following is from the regex(7) manpage:

```
An atom followed by '*' matches a sequence of 0 or more matches of  the  atom.
```

This means that in your regex, you are saying "match 0 or more space". If you want to match 0 or more of any character, you need `.*`.

```
ntpq -p | grep "10 L .* 64 377 0.000 0.000 0.001"
```

Although, you likely want to match "one or more of any character":

```
ntpq -p | grep -E "10 L .+ 64 377 0.000 0.000 0.001"
```

Even better, only match numbers or `-`:

```
ntpq -p | grep -E "10 L [[:digit:].\-]+ 64 377 0.000 0.000 0.001"
```

Comment: Your a life saver.. The ,* worked perfectly. I tried [[:digit:].-]+ and couldnt get it to work for some reason, but no worries.

Comment: @36DDJuicer - I updated the answer. It's because - is special inside of a character class and must be escaped. If you found the answer helpful, you should "accept" it.

Comment: Why would they break the most common convention? I don't see any reason to other than to make it more complicated and less familiar to the average user.